# Problems with Left shift key

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, keys

I have major (At least as for my job as a coder) hiccups with the Lshift.
I can't mark text in a textbox with LeftShift and arrowkeys, or type a capital letter with it.

WHAT I CAN do, which I think eliminates the keyboard to be the source of the problem is:
1.ALT+LeftShift to switch language. 2.While LeftShifting selecting text **with the mouse**
in a web page.

**More Info:**
In a keys thread elsewhere on AskUbuntu, someone suggested using `xev`, Here is the output for **right** shift key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x295, subw 0x0, time 49716012, (103,94), root:(306,867),
    state 0x10, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x295, subw 0x0, time 49716396, (103,94), root:(306,867),
    state 0x11, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

and here is for the **left** one:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967189 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

All keys but Super and lshift produce a keypress\release event, those two produce focusout\in then keymap notify, is this normal?

How should I go about tracing the cause and fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

A possible reason could be your choice of hot key for switching languages. If the SHIFT key is in that combination, then this could interfere with the input boxes.

Possible solution: change hot key (remove SHIFT) from the menu item "Text Entry Settings...", you can find this menu item if you click on the language icon at the top right of the unity desktop.

Comment: Can you please explain better? I have Ubuntu 18.04 and do not find the "Text Entry Settings"here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 14, I had similar problem. When quickly typing and using Left SHIFT I had many problems. Moving cursor, disappearing focus, and so on.

I have solved by going into the Settings-> Keyboard -> Typing -> (Switch to next source) : Disabled.

It was set to Left SHIFT + Right SHIFT, I have disabled. But you may want to set it to some other shortcut.